# How does one integrate the Fermi-Dirac distribution using the zeta function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

I've seen in my physics book that:

$$n=\frac{g}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{E^2dE}{e^{E/T}\pm1}$$

Regarding the number density of a relativistic gas of either bosons ($-1$) or fermions ($+1$). The solution of both of the integrals is given to be:

$$n_b=\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}gT^3$$
$$n_f=\frac{3}{4}\frac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}gT^3$$

Where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. I can see how the first one is obtained, since it's very straightforward using:

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$
$$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$

However, I don't see how the one for the fermions is integrated, since the denominator is $e^x \boldsymbol{+} 1$ instead of $e^x \boldsymbol{-} 1$, as the Riemann's zeta function has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a hint, try to show that:

$$\frac{1}{e^{E/T}+1} = \frac{1}{e^{E/T}-1} - \frac{2}{e^{2E/T}-1}.$$